# Error setting up redux-persist in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to set up redux-persist in a react-native project that is already using redux. I can not get it to work though.

I followed this article: https://medium.com/differential/building-offline-first-react-native-apps-b958acac0009#.vmshi0cxk

This is my set up in app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Navigator, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';

import * as reducers from '../reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

configureStore = (onComplete) => {
    const store = autoRehydrate()(createStoreWithMiddleware)(reducers);
    persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, onComplete);

    return store;
};
```

And the begining of App (in the same file):

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        store: configureStore(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false })),
      };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) return null;
        ....
    }
}
```

I get "reducer is not a function" as an error when trying this.

In the /reducers folder I have index.js:

```
import recordReducer from './recordReducer';

export {
  recordReducer
};
```

and in recordReducer.js:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {};

export default function recordReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {    
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SAVE_RECORDING_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        recordings: state.recordings ? state.recordings.concat([action.recording]) : [action.recording]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess - but according to the documentation you need to `import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'`, didn't see the import in your code.

Comment: I added that, but it did not solve the problem.